# Getting User id to proceed with Login

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am making a small webpage, and I want to extract the user id, so as to check whether the account exists or not. I do this by connecting to a MySQL DB, and checking to see if the account exists. I am very new to all of this, and only know the absolute basics of PHP & MySQL. Here is my login.php:

**login.php**

```
    <?php

    $server = "fooServer";
    $user = "foo";
    $pass = "foo";
    $db = "newsContent";                    
    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 
?>

<?php 
    $email = $_POST['email']; //Taken from my index.php
    $password = $_POST['password']; //Taken from my index.php

/*I used this so as to extract the id. I then wanted to
proceed with the procedure if the id existed, and alert the user if it didn't*/
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM fooTable WHERE username='$email' && password='$password'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "
    <script>
        alert('Login Successful');
        window.location.href='news.php';
    </script>";
    } else {
        <script>
        alert('Login unuccessful. User account does not exist');
        window.location.href='news.php';
    </script>";
    }
?>
```

This code may look horrific to experienced programmers, which I understand, but please fire-away with suggestions.

Comment: What's your problem regarding this code?

Comment: (1) you are open to sql injection as you are using your user data without sanitizing / using prepared statements. (2) are your passwords plaintext? not a good idea. (3) you only check if the query executed successfully, but don't check if it returned a row.

Comment: Try with a username of `' or 1=1--`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use user input as part of an SQL query, you risk SQL injection vulnerabilities. While you could go with prepared statements or a lot of sanitizing, the most robust approach i have seen so far is something like this:

```
function authenticate($email, $password) {

    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) return false;

    $auth = false;
    $check = false;
    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY email ASC";
    $knownUsers = $this -> sql -> doMultiSelect($q1);

    $checkUser = "";

    foreach ($knownUsers AS $user){
        if ($user ['email'] == $email) {
            $check = true;
            $checkUser = $user;
            break;
        }
        if (substr($user['email'],0,1) > substr($email,0,1)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($check) {
        if ($checkUser['password'] == crypt($password, $email) ) {
            $auth = true;
            // do something with the user data
        }
    } else {
        $this -> logActivity("failed login attempt for user ".$email);
    }
    return $auth;
}
```

Obviously you need to adapt that a bit for your needs.

This approach never passes the user input to the database, but the database is only used for reading.

Please note that this approach is good enough for a couple hundreds or maybe thousands of users, but not for very large numbers of existing users.

One more point: you may want to use the user's ID for further processing, but rather use something that cannot easily be guessed. Maybe an MD5 of the user's email or something along those lines.

Comment: :o I have never seen this way of authenticating a user and I think if you really want to make sure that your not getting any sql injections you should use PDO

Comment: @Szenis of course PDo would be an option. But depending on the type of project changing the way you communicate with the database is not necessarily a viable option. What that approach does provide is a bullet-proof way of preventing injection (unless i have overlooked something?)

Comment: this is overkill. there is no reason to get every user and than loop over in php. Both `mysqli` and `PDO` offer safe ways to query the database with user data, so this is not neccessary.

Comment: also, your function example uses custom functions - `doMultiSelect()` / `logActivity()` - which will confuse others looking at this example. Also, with a basic function, you have a scope issue with your db connection, but as you have `$this -> sql -> doMultiSelect()` are we to assume you are using a php class (which means this a class method, not a basic function).

Comment: @Sean Since i was trying to show the general principle and the mechanism of finding the user's data, i left out the custom functions (and the rest of the class), since i assume it is clear what they do, independent of their implementation. Also, they are irrelevant to the OP's question (to my understanding, that is).